# Do you believe that all the papers which are published do really deserve to be published?

Tags: publications, phd, peer-review, editors

Have you ever felt that the paper you are reading from a reputable journal did not deserve to be published?

Comment: Some people will answer "yes", and other people will answer "no". What's the point of this question?

Comment: @ZevChonoles Do you *really* think anybody will answer yes?  If so, I want to hear them speak!

Comment: @jakebeal: I don't understand your question. It appears as if you consider it doubtful that some people will say yes, but in fact you've posted a "yes" answer yourself. Why is it ridiculous for me to have (correctly) predicted that some people would say yes?

Comment: @jakebeal: Moreover, my comment simply points out that this question, as written, does not ask for any information further than "yes" or "no" (presumably you wouldn't be interested in hearing a bunch of people speaking if all they said was the word "yes"). There has to be a request for some kind of details, and an explanation of the purpose of gathering this information here on Stack Exchange. Otherwise, I'd say this is clearly "too broad" considering that there is an entire website [Retraction Watch](http://retractionwatch.com/) devoted to just a specific kind of "undeserving" papers.

Comment: @ZevChonoles I meant will anybody answer "Yes, all the papers should be published"

Comment: Obviously there exists at least one paper that shouldn't have been published, and there are several reasons why this could happen. E.g. fabricated data, plagiarism, etc.

Comment: @Jim Conant: What action(s) should be taken in such cases? or we don't have to do anything as readers?

Comment: Additional questions should be asked as questions, not inserted as comments.

Comment: @JeffE As noted above, there's an inversion between question and answer, which has caused the "yes" and "no" confusion.  I think we'd all be startled if anybody claimed every published paper really should have been published.

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely, sometimes bad work gets published that shouldn't get published.  To pick one particularly notorious case off the top of my head, consider the case of [Jacques Benveniste's "water memory" article in Nature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacques_Benveniste).

Likewise, sometimes good work has a hard time getting published.  To adulterate [Churchill's famous quote on democracy](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Winston_Churchill#Post-war_years_.281945.E2.80.931955.29): No one pretends that peer review is perfect or all-wise. Indeed, it has been said that peer review is the worst form of determining the truth except all those other forms that have been tried from time to time.

Comment: For example: Williamson (2009) [Caterpillars evolved from onychophorans by hybridogenesis](http://www.pnas.org/content/106/47/19901.full) *Proc. Nat. Acad. Sci. USA*

Comment: My personal favorite is [A mathematical model for the determination of total area under glucose tolerance and other metabolic curves](http://diyhpl.us/~bryan/papers2/paperbot/A%20Mathematical%20Model%20for%20the%20Determination%20of%20Total%20Area%20Under%20Glucose%20Tolerance%20and%20Other%20Metabolic%20Curves.pdf), which reinvents the Riemann integral.